# Set initial value of form field in Django's admin formfield_for_foreignkey

Tags: django

I have following code in my Django admin:

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
     if db_field.name == 'affected_user':
         kwargs['initial'] = request.user.id
     return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

and `affected_user` field in the model looks like this:

```
affected_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I'd like to get from this is have `affected_user` assigned particular initial value. Unfortunately, it seems like it doesn't work because I am getting first record from the table as initial value, while requested user has ID in the middle.

Could someone explain why is that? What I know for sure is that is correctly enters this if statement. But doesn't keep my initial value.

Comment: kwargs['initial'] = {'affected_user': request.user.id}

Comment: @AndreyMaslov unfortunately, didn't help.

Comment: move this code to `get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)` method instead of `formfield_for_foreignkey`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov when moved to get_form that's the error `modelform_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    return {'affected_user': request.user}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Still it doesn't help. TBH I have no idea why is that. I've checked this method and it should return correctly. I'll keep digging.

Comment: we need to provide `user`, not `id`, changed answer

Comment: I think the issue I'm facing is because (at least at the moment) due to the fact that `get_changeform_initial_data(self, request)` is never called. I've added simple print and it didn't show.

Comment: it call this method only for new objects

Comment: That's what I didn't get. Thanks, that explains a lot!